# photoChooserTask Save and View Image in windows phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8

i use a photoChooserTask for select a image

i have this xaml

```
<Image Width="180" Height="180" Stretch="UniformToFill" Margin="10,10,0,0"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Source="{Binding ImagePhoto}"></Image>

<Button HorizontalAlignment="Left" click="ButtonAddPhoto_EventClick" content"select image">
```

In a cs file

```
 public void ButtonAddPhoto_EventClick()
        {

             _PhotoChooserTask = new PhotoChooserTask();
             _PhotoChooserTask.Completed += new EventHandler<PhotoResult>(photoChooserTask_Completed);
             _PhotoChooserTask.Show();

        }

async void photoChooserTask_Completed(object sender, PhotoResult e)
        {
            if (e.TaskResult == Microsoft.Phone.Tasks.TaskResult.OK)
            {

                string FileName = Path.GetFileName(e.OriginalFileName);

                StorageFolder tmpfolder = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFolderAsync("temp");
                StorageFile file = await tmpfolder.CreateFileAsync(_PhotoFileName, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
                using (Stream current = await file.OpenStreamForWriteAsync())
                {
                    await e.ChosenPhoto.CopyToAsync(current);
                }

                ImagePhoto = new Uri("isostore:/temp/" + FileName, UriKind.Absolute);

            }
        }
```

Image save to isolatedstorage but not view in a image. Why?
thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a Stream to read the image you just saved and then just set the source of your image to this stream. And bind the Image in your xaml too...

**EDIT**

```cs
private static BitmapImage GetImageFromIsolatedStorage(string imageName)
    {
        var bimg = new BitmapImage();
        using (var iso = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
        {
            using (var stream = iso.OpenFile(imageName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                bimg.SetSource(stream);
            }
        }
        return bimg;
    }
```