# Get Photo file Uri using PhotoChooserTask wp8

Tags: windows-phone-8, isolatedstorage, cameracapturetask

For my current project, i have an IEnumerable property ImageCollection as follow,

```
    public static IEnumerable<Uri> ImageCollection { get; set; }
```

Which holds a collection of all in-app photos available for user to choose. The feature includes user be able to choose from Gallery. I am using PhotoChooserTask and below code to set the Image Source using below code,

```
    private void photoChooserTask_Completed(object sender, PhotoResult e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (e.TaskResult == TaskResult.OK)
            {
                BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage();
                image.SetSource(e.ChosenPhoto);

                LibrImage.Source = image;

                ViewModelLocator.SelectedImage = image;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            Common.ShowMessageBox("Error occured while saving pic.");
        }
    }
```

However, i would want to store the reference, Uri or e.OriginalFileName, in database. I learnt that even if a store the copy in Isolated Storage, i will not be able to achieve what i am looking for -  Get a reference to the files chosen using photoChooserTask. I may be wrong.

Even though my initial idea was to add the Uri of Gallery file to my ImageCollection and store the index in database per item, Any suggestion or improvisation is appreciated.

Note: Added CameraCaptureTask Tag as PhotoChooserTask Tag is not available and the basic logic is same.

**EDIT** Code used to store and retrieve from IsolatedStorage

I am binding the result of GetImageFromIsolatedStorage() method to me Image control source. This doesnt work.. What am i doing wrong...

```
public static string SaveImageToIsolatedStorage(BitmapImage bitImg)
        {
            string fname = null;

            if (bitImg != null)
            {
                fname = GetImageName();

                WriteableBitmap wbmp = new WriteableBitmap(bitImg);
                IsolatedStorageFile isf = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
                using (isf)
                {
                    if (isf.FileExists(fname)) { isf.DeleteFile(fname); }

                    using (var stream = isf.OpenFile(fname, System.IO.FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
                    {
                        wbmp.SaveJpeg(stream, bitImg.PixelWidth, bitImg.PixelHeight, 0, 100);
                        stream.Close();
                    }
                }
            }

            return fname;
        }

        private static string GetImageName()
        {
            return string.Format(
                "{0}/GalleryImage{1}.jpg",
                FileDir,
                ImageCount++);
        }

        public static BitmapImage GetImageFromIsolatedStorage(string fname)
        {
            BitmapImage img = new BitmapImage();
            try
            {
                using (IsolatedStorageFile isf = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
                {
                    using (IsolatedStorageFileStream fileStream = isf.OpenFile(fname, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
                    {
                        img.SetSource(fileStream);
                        fileStream.Close();
                    }
                }
            }
            catch { }

            return img;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

That is not possible. ChooserTask and complete access to the device's library are two different things in Windows Phone.

Either you specify that your app has complete access to the library and handle it this way or use ChooserTask, let the user select photo (there is also ability to crop it) and then save this image into app's isolated storage.

Comment: Even if a I store the image to phones Isolated storage, I will not be able to refer it by Uri, is it?

Comment: i am referring [THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22375669/photochoosertask-save-and-view-image-in-windows-phone-8?rq=1) thread to proceed as you suggested.

Comment: If you save the image to isolated storage, then yes, you can refer ib by Uri. Because your app has complete access to the isolated storage.

Comment: can you guide/refer me with some working sample, i as able to save it but am not able to read it back using Uri. have updated the code i am trying...

Comment: Instead of calling method, you can simply get the image using this: new Uri("isostore:/[yourFolder]/GalleryImage2.png", UriKind.Absolute);